# How to access html element using node relationship of html DOM in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to access html element by node relationship likes parentNode,fastChild,nextSibling etc.But my following code not work properly.
My Code looks like :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>This is first para</p>

        <div id="mydiv">
            <h2 align="center">This is the Header</h1>
            <p align="justify">This is the Paragraph</p>
            <marquee scrolldelay="10">This is maquee</marquee>
        </div>

        <p>This is last para</p>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
            alert(mydiv.parentNode + "\n" +
                  mydiv.firstChild + "\n" +
                  mydiv.childNodes[1] + "\n" +
                  mydiv.lastChild + "\n" +
                  mydiv.previousSibling + "\n" +
                  mydiv.nextSibling);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

OUTPUT in alert box looks like :

```
[object HTMLBodyElement]
[object Text]
[object HTMLHeadingElement]
[object Text]
[object Text]
[object Text]
```

But for the div,the parentNode,fastChild,childNodes[1],lastChild,previousSibling and nextSibling should be body,h2,p,marquee,p and p.So why output is looks like above?

Comment: Use .parentElement, not Node, if you want to skip the text :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whitespace before/after the various elements is turned into text nodes. You can see the results you want if you remove all spaces:

```
<p>This is first para</p><div id="mydiv"><h2 align="center">This is the Header</h1><p align="justify">This is the Paragraph</p><marquee scrolldelay="10">This is maquee</marquee></div><p>This is last para</p>
```

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/hpIow

The [MDN `Node.firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.firstChild) docs explain this in more detail.

Note that the equivalent jQuery methods will ignore the text nodes and give you the children, next nodes, etc. that you want.

You can also loop over child nodes, skipping text nodes until you find something else:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < mydiv.childNodes.length; ++i )
{
  if (mydiv.childNodes[i].nodeType != Node.TEXT_NODE)
  {
    firstNon = mydiv.childNodes[i];
    break;
  }
}
```

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/chLCo

Comment: All are run ok except lastChild.It returns [object HTMLDivElement] but I think it should returns marquee object.

Comment: Working as expected for me in the sample link.

Comment: Hm. Marquee in Chrome, Div in Firefox.

Comment: It's the right element. For whatever internal reasons, Firefox is implementing as an HTMLDivElement under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [firstElementChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.firstElementChild) to bypass that whitespace (or just use an existing js library if what are you doing isn't meant just for learning purposes, dealing with the DOM yourself isn't a very pleasant experience)

Comment: true that, but if you want cross browser and backwards compatibility, you shouldn't try to reinvent the wheel, it's easier to use a well tested js library, like jQuery